# Nginx If-Modified-Since sometimes is ignored

Tags: caching, nginx

Css files are picked from the cache, so i have to manually edit file version `style.css?v=2` for example, to force cache reset.

On my PC everything is ok, but many people telling, that they have old logo or old design stuff from the last version of css file. Meaning they are taken from the cache.

How to fix this via nginx?

I'm already thinking about solution to dynamically append modify time to all css files like this `style.css?v=%last file modify time%`

The only caching thing inside my nginx conf is this line:

```
expires 1y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When modified is omitted expires will allow the browser to cache a file based on the request time. Read the mod_header documentation for all the details.

Comment: Why would modified be omitted?